# What does the "invalid"-tag mean in `npm list`?

Tags: node.js, npm, package-managers

Given the following snippet of `npm list` output:

```
...
├─┬ glob@6.0.2 invalid
│ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.4
│ │ └── wrappy@1.0.1
│ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ ├── minimatch@2.0.10
│ └── once@1.3.3
...
```

I asked myself: "What does invalid mean?" However, all I could [find](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdocs.npmjs.com%2F+invalid) in the documentation about it is the following:

> [npm list] will print out extraneous, missing, and invalid packages. --[source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)

...So now I'm asking you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `invalid` tag appears when the version of the installed dependency does not match the version required in `package.json`. Often this will occur when a dependency is required in `dependencies` as well as an incompatible version in `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen if you mistakenly write something inside the dependencies,

For example:

[image]

I mistakenly write something inside @sendgrid/mail

It suppose to be  "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0", not  "@sendgrid/mail": **"^7.7.dd0",**